# 1 Paged Data Source with multiple datatables from a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater which gets data from a pageddatasrouce. This pageddatasource gets data from a dataset. I usually do this when using only one table in the dataset and now I would like the pageddatasource to get data from 2 tables which are in the dataset with relation between them.

This is the code I usually use when working with 1 table in the dataset.

```
        PagedDataSource Pds = new PagedDataSource();

        Pds.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        Pds.AllowPaging = true;
        Pds.PageSize = 2;
        Pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

        lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + Pds.PageCount.ToString();

        // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
        cmdPrev.Enabled = !Pds.IsFirstPage;
        cmdNext.Enabled = !Pds.IsLastPage;

        Repeater1.DataSource = Pds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
```

I tried using the code below for the 2 tables but it only uses table 1, or if I flip them it will use table 2.

```
    Pds.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView; //table 1
    Pds.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[1].DefaultView; //table 2
```

Could anyone please guide me what to do to be able to use both tables

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed my own problem :)

Instead of requesting the 2 datatables separately from the database and then adding them to a dataset, I used a JOIN statement which resulted in both tables combined into 1 datatable and then added to a dataset.

The datasource was then given the dataset with 1 datatable as I posted in my question.